# SKSpriteNode animation where each frame in the animation is not centered

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, ios10, skspritenode, sprite-sheet

I have a `SKSpriteNode` which is 120px x 120px.
The default texture of the sprite is just a circle with radius of 60px.
I would like to animate the sprite with:

```
SKAction.animate(with:timePerFrame:resize:restore:)
```

The issue is that each texture as part of the animation is less than 120px x 120px in size, and hence if I do this and set the sprite anchor point to

```
CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

The animation frames will be centered at the middle of the sprite, which is not the correct animation I am after. I would like the animation to be as follows:

[image]

That means that I must add all the animation textures in the sprite atlas to be 120px x 120px, am I correct? if so, this will result in wasted atlas space with empty pixels. Is there any better way of achieving this? i.e. specifying the centre point of each texture frame in the animation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to try also:

[image]

Focus your attention to  `resize = true` 
If **true**, the sprite is resized to match each new texture. If **false**, the size of the sprite remains at a constant size.

If you need more official details take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417656-animate).

---

About your request to the comments below you can re-create `SKAction.animate` for example make an extension like this:

```
extension SKAction
{
    static func animate(withMyTextures textures:[texture:SKTexture], timePerFrame:TimeInterval ,resize:Bool, restore:Bool) ->SKAction {

        var originalTexture : SKTexture!
        let duration = timePerFrame * Double(textures.count)

        return SKAction.customAction(withDuration: duration)
        {
            node,elapsedTime in
            guard let spriteNode = node as? SKSpriteNode
            else
            {
                    assert(false,"animateWithMyTextures only works on members of SKSpriteNode")
                    return
            }
            let index = Int((elapsedTime / CGFloat(duration)) * CGFloat(textures.count))
            //If we havent assigned this yet, lets assign it now
            if originalTexture == nil
            {
                originalTexture = spriteNode.texture
            }
            if(index < textures.count)
            {
                spriteNode.texture = textures[index].texture
            }
            else if(restore)
            {
                spriteNode.texture = originalTexture
            }
            if(resize)
            {
                spriteNode.size = spriteNode.texture!.size()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an issue of resizing. this is an issue of positioning each frame of the animation in the correct position. If I set resize = true, the sprite will simply resize with each frame of animation. Please have a look at the second row in the diagram above. thats how the each frame should be positioned during the animation.

Comment: If this is not an issue of resizing,you have wrong to make your animation. How can you expect simple images are positioned on the right or left basing on your tastes,after that you have inserted in a transparent environment?There are two problems here: one is the different size caused by the trasparent area in the top/bottom of your sprites (solved by resize=true) , the other is that you should move your pieces on the side you want, otherwise you should remake the animation putting a simple pixel of reference to the transp. area to maintain real width dimension (or change the background color)

Comment: The issue is not resizing. The question really is, is there a way to position each texture frame of the animation separately or for example, set different anchor points for each animation texture frame? e.g. frame01 anchor point (0.0, 0.5), second frame anchor point (0.25, 0.5), third frame anchor point (0.5,0.5) ...etc. Because if I have each texture with empty pixels in the atlas, then that is a waste of memory for holding empty pixels.

Comment: That's a reasonable question. About it, if you using `SKAction.animate` you cannot do it. But, you always re-create by code the "animate" action to intercept every single sprite with texture during the custom animate and decide your size for every single sprite: seems a little uncomfortable but it's the only way by code. The other way , as I said, it's to re-make your animation. P.S. I've update my answer to help you to make a custom `SKAction.animate`, good luck for your project.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thanks.